# Why can I not run (text-scale-increase 2) in emacs 26.1 running in terminal?

Tags: terminal-emacs

How come, when running (text-scale-increase 2) from the scratch buffer in an emacs instance running in a terminal, nothing happens besides a counter in the status-bar increasing? In particular, nothing happens to the font size. When doing this in gui-emacs, it works fine.

I am trying to tie a custom key-chord in the kitty terminal (https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/), sending a utf-8 code unicode char to emacs running in the terminal and then bind that unicode char to (text-scale-increase). However, since (text-scale-increase) for some reason does not execute properly in the terminal it fails. Also, when trying (text-scale-increase) in an ordinary gnome-terminal, it also fails.

What is at work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the terminal, the font you're using is determined solely by your terminal emulator, not by Emacs. Emacs only has control over the fonts when running in gui mode.